# How to use vlookup function where lookup table array is dynamic?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

How to use vlookup function where lookup table array is dynamic? I find the column where I need to lookup values using MATCH function. Can you please suggest how to put integer value coming from MATCH to lookup array function.

Comment: You can use Indirect Function for that. Construct the Address using Variables in InDirect Function.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is all you're asking, but if you're trying to match the column, you can just include the entire range of the spreadsheet. Or you could use an Index function to resize. Lots of options.

To directly answer your question, here's a dynamic vlookup that will include any possible row (as it extends all the way to the bottom of the spreadsheet), and uses `Match`, to lookup the column header `DONKEY`. Not very elegant, but it'll get you started. In this case the formula would return 49.

Here's the formula if you want it: `=VLOOKUP("California",$I$5:$XFD$1048576,MATCH("Donkey",i4:$XFD$4,0),0)`

[image]

**UPDATE** somehow the above answer has gotten two likes so I will make a bigger effort to enhance this answer by explaining that [Index Function](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/index_function.php) would probably be a better approach than Vlookup. The formula would look like this: `=INDEX(J5:M7,MATCH("Cobra Kia",I5:I7,0),MATCH("Donkey",J4:M4,0),1)`

Also, OP tagged `VBA` although it doesn't seem like this is needed. However if using VBA and trying to do MATCH, always us `Application.Match` approach, even though it doesn't auto populate like `Application.WorksheetFunction.Match`. I wrote about that too [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21839958/match-not-working-excel-error-1004-unable-to-get-the-match-property/56481450#56481450)... (still not as good as my SHA256!)

[image]

Comment: Sorry first screen shot was wrong. I started giving an index answer.

Comment: I would definitely give the index function as a alternative too!

Comment: @JvdV done! I don't know how this answer has more likes than this answer I spent literally almost all day on.... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46509572/excel-formula-based-function-for-sha256-sha512-hashing-without-vba-or-macros/56767828#56767828